# Store UTF8 data in UTF16 column

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml

I'm storing XML in an XML column in SQL Server. SQL Server stores the data internally in UTF-16. Therefore the XML that is stored has to be in UTF-16.

The XML I have is in utf-8, it has this declaration on top:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
```

When I try to insert xml with the UTF-8 declaration I get an exception saying something about the encoding. I can easily fix this in two ways:

- by removing the declaration or
- by changing the declaration to

:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16" ?>
```

**Problem**

I don't know if it's 'safe' or correct to just remove or replace the declaration. Will I lose data, or will the XML become corrupt? Or do I have to convert the string in C# from utf-8 to utf-16?

Comment: It's always a good idea to quote any exceptions that you get and currently do not understand.

Comment: If you store the files as text, then store them as text (i.e. treat them as such too, which means applying a universal encoding). Of course that would require you to remove the inline encoding declaration. I'd just store them as blobs, though which gets rid of such considerations.

Comment: SQL Server stores data internally as UCS-2, not UTF-16. This only really matters if you are using UTF-16 surrogate pairs.

Comment: how big is the xml? if it is small, you can trivially load it in C# and save to a StringWriter, which will use UTF-16

Comment: @Ed Harper: Perhaps you could explain what happens if you read a surrogate pair in C# and transmit it to SQL Server?  Especially if you put `encoding="UTF-16"` on a C# string which must be UCS-2.

Comment: @Andomar - It simply gets inserted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C# stores strings in UCS-2, an older version of the UTF-16 standard.  So when you read a UTF-8 string in C#, C# converts it to UCS-2.  It's the UCS-2 variant that you transmit to SQL Server.

You can change the xml declaration to `encoding="UTF-16"` or omit it altogether.  There are some differences between UCS-2 and UTF-16; I'd be interesting in knowing how that affects C# and SQL Server!

Comment: The differences have little practical impact.  UCS-2 can only represent the 16bit part of the 21bit Unicode (called BMP).  But if a non-BMP character occurs in the data, which is very rare with most languages, they are represented with two "surrogates" each and get through anyway.  You might get inaccurate `DATALENGTH` values but you would probably never notice.

Comment: @JirkaHanika: So while UTF-16 adds an additional way to represent non -BMP characters, it doesn't invalidate the old way?

Comment: It doesn't.  But SQL Server will simply continue to treat it as a fixed width encoding, treating a non-BMP character as two "characters".  For example if you have an `nvarchar(1)` column, you won't fit a non-BMP character into it at all.

Comment: @JirkaHanika: So it would be valid to transmit a non-BMP character as a surrogate pair with `encoding="utf-16"` in the XML declaration?

Comment: Absolutely.  I don't know whether the driver cannot convert other encodings as well in some versions, but UTF16 and UCS2 is the same thing as long as you don't have to interpret the content (e.g., count characters).

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server internally uses UCS-2 to store XML data, but this has nothing to do with the form in which you pass the data to SQL Server.

If for example you insert it using a `varchar` literal, make it an `nvarchar` literal instead and declare the encoding to be UTF-16.  Sample:

```
DECLARE @VAR XML
INSERT INTO MyTable (MyXmlColumn) 
    VALUES (N'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16" ?><doc></doc>')
```

Comment: The OP mentioned a C# client, so he's probably not using SQL literals